# Can I call this a footrest?

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary

*This question was originally two questions, and has now been split. The other part of the question can be found [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6388/what-is-the-hole-in-this-object-called)*

---

[image: desk with "footrest" (?) (see arrow)]

It is a thing that is attached to a desk and onto which we can place our feet. Can I call this a "footrest"?
Is it correct if I say "You can place your feet on the footrest"?

Comment: This looks like it might be two questions ("*can I call this a footrest?*" and "*what is the name for this hole?*"). If true, you will need to split this into two questions.

Comment: If you've ever been in a coffee shop in the US you will notice that everything is used as a footrest even if it isn't called a footrest. ;)

Comment: For first question: Yes! search footrests' images for student desks. And for the second one: It is better to say drawers. According to the wiki definition of desk: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DeskDesks: Desks often have one or more drawers, compartments, or pigeon holes to store office supplies and papers.

Comment: It's not really a footrest. The purpose of the bottom crosspiece there is to stabilize the desk frame. Without it, the legs will splay and the desk will break. It's just a coincidence that it serves as a footrest. Unless you believe in some kind of intelligent design. If so, you can call it a footrest.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone! It's helpful and useful! @ Bill Franke I agree with you that in fact it might not be  really a footrest. However, finally I wonder I might call call it "a footrest" because it's easy for me. :)

Comment: I've split this question into two, after the OP failed to split the question themselves. The second part can now be found here: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6388/what-is-the-hole-in-this-object-called

Answer (score 7):

You *can* call it a footrest, but if it's not obviously designed to serve that purpose, you are probably better off calling it by a more generic name, in this case "crossbar".  For the desk shown, I'd say that "crossbar" is the better choice since there's no pad or other foot-sized flat surface on the bar where your feet can fit comfortably.

Comment: In joinery the crossbar is called a ["stretcher"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stretcher_(furniture)).

Comment: Thanks a lot Hellion for explanations and new words (crossbar and compartment). It's useful.

Comment: I'd tend to call that bar "a crossbar that I'm using as a footrest". :-)