# What is the “hole” in this desk called?

Tags: word-choice, image-identification

*This question has been created to split two questions previously asked [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6351/can-i-call-this-a-footrest)*

---

[image: plain wooden desk with empty draw space]

It is a "hole" in a desk. What can I call this? Can I say "Put your books into the hole"?

Comment: I'd just call it a *shelf*.

Comment: Honestly, I'd just say "put your books in your desk" and not bother naming it at all.  That said, if I were asked to name it, I'd probably use cubby (first instinct), shelf, or maybe drawer, despite the fact that you don't pull it open.

Answer (score 11):

That internal area is called a "compartment". (If it had a container that you could slide out to place your things inside more readily, that would be a "drawer".)

(A "hole" is too generic of a term, and would not be associated with the desk; a "slot" would be a long, narrow hole that allows you to insert, for example, an envelope into an otherwise closed compartment.  [This desk](http://s3images.coroflot.com/user_files/individual_files/original_287305_xsPMPWdVwRi1NKatQUUJ_PwW1.jpg) has a (closed) drawer with a slot.)

Answer (score 10):

I would use one of the following terms:
• *[pigeonhole](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pigeonhole#Noun)*, “A nook in a desk for holding papers”
• *[recess](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/recess#Noun)*, “An inset, hole, space or opening”
• *[cubbyhole](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cubbyhole#Noun)*, “A small compartment; a pigeonhole”
• *desk pocket*, with [pocket](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pocket#Noun) used in the sense of a receptacle, indention, or cavity

Comment: I have specific preconceptions about all those terms (except "desk pocket", which I haven't heard) that would prevent me from using them: *pigeonholes* occur in multiples and are usually sized for holding envelopes or folded papers; *recesses* are shallow, not extending the full depth of the item; *cubbyholes* have (approximately) square openings, not short and wide.

Comment: Your preconception for *pigeonhole* is sense 2, “one of an array of compartments...”,  at the reference I gave.  I referred to sense 1.  Your preconception that a cubbyhole has an (approximately) square opening seems idiosyncratic; do you have any evidence it isn't idiosyncratic?

Comment: Well, there's google image search for "cubbyhole" where the relevant results (ignoring strip clubs, bars, etc.) mostly agree with me, but otherwise I don't have a reference.  I should also say that cubbyholes are clearly larger than pigeonholes; if I were going to define a difference between them, I'd say that if you can stand an average paperback book upright in it, it's too big for "pigeonhole" and must be a "cubbyhole" (or "nook", or "compartment", depending on its shape, I suppose) instead.

Answer (score 5):

The hole in that desk can be called a slot. See [this definiton](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/slot_1?q=slot).

Answer (score 5):

One could call the "compartment" a *cubby*, a *cubbyhole*, a *pigeonhole* (although a pigeonhole is usually smaller), or a *recess*, but the simplest, most common English word might be *shelf*.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from anything else *that* does not look practical. What would you put in there? Paper? Exercise books?

- I would not describe that space as being a slot.  A
  [**slot**](http://www.istockphoto.com/stock-photo-7357424-coin-slot.php)
  is a snug, tight hole, usually horizontal, and just enough space to
  slide something in. A coin for example. A slot machine, for example
  is another name for a fruit machine. In that case the coin slot is
  usually vertical.
- I wouldn't call it a hole. A
  [**hole**](http://lessismorphine.blogspot.it/2010/11/hole-in-wall-may-be-portal-into-new.html)
  tends to be round, not always, but if you were to ask someone to draw
  a hole in the wall it would be round shaped.
- Personally I would call it an "open drawer" or a "paper drawer"  or
  "an open unit" or a "paper storage nook". Google provided this
  possibility:

[**Open paper storage drawer**](http://www.gresswell.co.uk/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/L/0/L00004408_301-0619.jpg) The actual piece of furniture is called "a four drawer open paper storage".

But admittedly it is a bit of a mouthful. It would take you longer to say to a friend: " Please put the book into the open paper storage drawer." than to put the actual book away yourself. "Hole" then would be fine, life's too short.

Answer (score 0):

The most common parlance I've used for this is over my years in school was to just "put [object] in your desk." We usually don't refer to it as a compartment, but that would make sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you talking about one in a public space, such as a school, I think the best term I would suggest is "Doom Hole". Such as: "Woe betide anybody who put their hand in that doom hole."

Comment: *Why* would someone call it a doom hole? What happens when you put your hand in that compartment that is so negative that it qualifies for that designation?

Answer (score -1):

In the US, the most widely understood term would be **Cubbyhole**.